# Testing Django UserCreationForm - form.is_valid() always returning false

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write tests for my Django chat application to validate the UserCreationForm. I am following the Django test code here:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/auth_tests/test_forms.py

I have a users app which handle registration, login, etc.

#### users/tests.py

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserCreationFormTest(TestCase):

    def test_form(self):
        data = {
            'username': 'testuser',
            'password1': 'test123',
            'password2': 'test123',
        }

        form = UserCreationForm(data)

        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

I've extended the UserCreation form to include an email field (forms.py) when registering.

#### users/forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Email')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why

```py
form.is_valid()
```

always returns False during my testing. In my test I have

```py
self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

To execute tests I am running

```
python manage.py test users
```

from the terminal.

Actual registration, login, etc. works fine but my tests do not work as expected!

#### users/views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():  # check if valid
            form.save()  # save user info
            messages.success(
                request, f'Your account has been created. You are now able to login.')
            return redirect('/users/login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Register'})
```

Comment: I presume it is because email is a required field, and you are not passing it. However you could verify this for yourself by putting l printing form.errors in your test.

Comment: Thank you. Printing form.errors allowed me to solve the issue. Turns out it was throwing an error because my test passwords were too weak! Django authentication is too good! I didn't know form.errors existed, so thanks for this.